# Specify number of hops(recursive query) when selecting graphs in surrealdb

Tags: surrealdb

I'm trying to implement tree using surreal db. My tree looks like this.
[image]

```
create node:root set title = 'Root';
create node:child1 set title = 'Child 1';
create node:child2 set title = 'Child 2';
create node:child3 set title = 'Child 3';
create node:grandchild11 set title = 'GrandChild 1.1'
relate node:root -> is_parent -> node:child1;
relate node:root -> is_parent -> node:child2;
relate node:root -> is_parent -> node:child3;
relate node:child1 -> is_parent -> node:grandchild11;
```

And now i want to select subtree starting from root recursively(eg being able to specify number of hops).

I tried this query and didn't quite understand how to archive recursiveness using this syntax.

```
select *,->is_parent->node as childen from node:root;
```

This query returns subtree but only for one level down.

So is there a way to specify number of hops or perform graph traversal recursively to get structure something like this.

```
{
  "title": "root',
  "children": [
    "title": "child1",
    "children": [
       {
         "title": "grandchild 1.1"
       }
    ],
    ...other root children nodes
  ]
}
```